# Change the distance unit from iphone settings

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode

I am developing a location based iphone application which searches the near by stores based on the distance. I used the standard unit of distance in Kilometer. But i want to change the unit of distance according to the standard unit of each Countries. Can i able to change the unit of distance from the iphone settings ? The distance format should be location based default: in South Africa: KM, in the States: MI.
I want to get it in the following units also - o Feet o Miles o Nautical Miles o Meters o Kilometers o Ri (Korea) o Ri (Japan) o ETC!!! –

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can get the locale that the phone is set to this way:

```
NSLocale *locale = [NSLocale currentLocale];
```

and ask it about units of measure this way:

```
NSString *measurementSystem = [locale objectForKey: NSLocaleMeasurementSystem];
```

This will answer “Metric” or “U.S.”.   There's a lot more you can check in the [NSLocale class ref](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSLocale_Class/Reference/Reference.html).

Comment: Can i able to get it in the following units o   Feet

o   Miles

o   Nautical Miles

o   Meters

o   Kilometers

o   Ri (Korea)

o   Ri (Japan)

o   ETC!!!

Comment: Do some multiplication? For example km / 1.6 -> u.s. mi

Comment: You should not use @"NSLocaleMeasurementSystem" as NSString, instead use the constant provided by Apple: NSLocaleMeasurementSystem.

Answer (score 2):

No you can not change the distance unit. What you should use is `NSLocaleUsesMetricSystem` from [NSLocale](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSLocale_Class/Reference/Reference.html)